# Divide a Chess Game into two parts and show individual moves using a looping code using xskak package

Tags: chess, chessboard, xskak

Following is a game which has two parts - 
First part - Opening moves and 
Second part - then start to analyse the further moves. 
For this I create a game firstgame1 and display the moves using \looping{1} macro. And then create firstgame2 again till moves 5w and post that add more moves using mainline, but then the ready state till 5w of firstgame2 is what the looping macro is not build to work I feel. Please suggest any changes that can be made into looping macro like passing the moveid of loop starting of the game or anything which experts can suggest.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\usepackage[ps,normal]{skak}
\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{minibox}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    left=1cm,
    right=1cm,
    top=3cm,
    bottom=2cm}

% \looping macro start of code ::: 
    \newcommand\getmovestyle[1]{%
    \ifthenelse
      {\equal{#1}{N}}%knight move
      {\def\mymovestyle{[clockwise=false,style=knight]curvemove}}%
      {\ifthenelse
        {\equal{#1}{}}% castling
        {\def\mymovestyle{curvemove}}%
        {\def\mymovestyle{straightmove}}}}%

    \newcommand{\looping}[1]{
    %   \chessboard[setfen=\xskakgetgame{initfen}]% Show me the empty board.
    \xskakloop[step=#1]
    { \begin{tabular}{c}
    \getmovestyle{\xskakget{piecechar}}%
    \chessboard[tinyboard,
    %       id=#2,
            pgfstyle=\mymovestyle, 
            color=blue,
            markmoves=\xskakget{move}, 
            pgfshortenend=0.3em, 
            arrow=to, 
            coloremph, 
            color=red, 
            markstyle=circle, 
            markfield=\xskakget{movefrom},
            emphfields=\xskakget{moveto}, 
            setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}]
        \\  \xskakget{opennr}\xskakget{san}
        \end{tabular}
      }% End of \xskakloop...
    }
    % the looping code - Borrowed from tex.stackexchange



    \begin{document}
    \title{Learning Chess}
    \maketitle
    \tableofcontents

    \chapter{An Advantage in development}
    \section{Rapid development}
    \newchessgame[id=firstgame1,white=Mikhail Tal, black=Wolfgang Uhlmann]
    \subsubsection{\xskakgetgame{white}--\xskakgetgame{black}}
    \mainline{1.e4 e6 2.d4 d5 3. Nd2 c5 4. Ngf3 Nc6 5. Bb5}

    % Printing the opening moves step by step : Part 1 
    \looping{1}


    % Part II - created to show the moves after Opening moves.
    % Setting the opening move for showing moves using looping macro from 5b move.
    \newchessgame[white=Mikhail Tal, black=Wolfgang Uhlmann,id=firstgame2,moveid=5b,
        setfen={r1bqkbnr/pp3ppp/2n1p3/1Bpp/3PP/5N/PPP2PPP/R1BQK2R}]
    % adding next moves which we need to show in looping macro.     
    \subsubsection{Further}
    \mainline{5...dxe4?!}
    \mainline{6. Nxe4 Bd7 7. Ng5}

    %current status of the board
    \showboard 

    % Looping macro to show moves from 5b but its not working, I am not able to understand what changes to make to the macro to make it work. 
    \looping{1}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Again no complete example. You are trying hard to alienate me.

Comment: I have mentioned my outcome, don't know how to code it, hence the question. In the above I have stated the code that creates the figures shown above, but the division and later looping by passing the gameid I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: Will try to work something and share. Thanks!

Comment: @nichas Just a minimal working code sample of your current attempt would be enough. Starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`, including just the necessary code to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I will work on the chessboard package and try my problem again. I think not working on chessboard package is not helping me understand or work. Thank!  @UlrikeFischer sorry for troubling you with incomplete questions. Thanks all. Will be back with problem understanding and format. Ulrike thanks for chess package you have made, its amazing.

Comment: You have an error in your game. The startfen is missing the knight on d3 and so move 6 Nxe4 is not possible, and this confuses the move parser. Correct the fen to `PPPN1PPP`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get error as the start position in your second game if wrong: You are missing the knight on d2.

Correct the fen like this:

```
 \newchessgame[white=Mikhail Tal, black=Wolfgang Uhlmann,id=firstgame2,moveid=5b,
        setfen={r1bqkbnr/pp3ppp/2n1p3/1Bpp/3PP/5N/PPPN1PPP/R1BQK2R}] %added knight
```

Your code for move 7 is wrong too. As there is a knight on e4 and one of f3 you have to tell which one is moving to g5 (e.g. the f-knight):

```
\mainline{6. Nxe4 Bd7 7. Nfg5}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.